# Revealing prototype pattern doesn't work with Array

Tags: javascript, prototype

**It works when I write** (http://jsfiddle.net/XJwvP/):

```
var Person = function(name) { this.name = name; }
Person.prototype = function () {
   var sayHello = function (name) {
         alert("Hello, " + name);
   };

   return {
      sayHello: sayHello
   };
}();

var person = new Person("Max");
person.sayHello("James");
```

**It doesn't work when I write**(http://jsfiddle.net/ZKd4R/):

```
Array.prototype = function () {
   var sayHello = function (name) {
         alert("Hello, " + name);
   };

   return {
      sayHello: sayHello
   };
}();

var array = new Array();
array.sayHello("James");
```

**Error**:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'sayHello'
```

Why I cannot use the same approach for Array object?

Comment: And **don't overwrite `Array.prototype`**!!!

Comment: It IS an object as far as I am using self calling function. And it works in the first case!

Comment: Ah Sorry, I failed to notice the IIFE.

Comment: @bfavaretto probably you are right... silly of me

Comment: In fact, that's the part that fails (silently). New Array instances will always grab the default Array.prototype. You can extend it, but not replace it.

Comment: Reference for my previous statement: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.2.1

Comment: @bfavaretto cool, man. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing `Array.prototype` like you did do not affect new `Array` instances, because the `Array` constructor is special in the language (it's a *built-in constructor*). The specification says at [15.4.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.2.1):

> The [[Prototype]] internal property of the newly constructed object is set to the original Array prototype object, the one that is the initial value of **Array.prototype** ([15.4.3.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.3.1)).

If you check [15.4.3.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.3.1), you'll note that `Array.prototype` is also not [[Writable]]. I just tested that in Chrome console:

```
var ap = Array.prototype;
Array.prototype = {};
ap == Array.prototype; // true
```

Answer (score 1):

@bfavaretto already explained *why* it not works. Here is the pattern you should use to avoid such problems:

```
function Person(name) { this.name = name; }
(function(proto) {
   function sayHello(name) {
         alert("Hello, " + name);
   }

   proto.sayHello = sayHello;
}(Person.prototype));

var person = new Person("Max");
person.sayHello("James");
```

```
(function(proto) {
    function sayHello(name) {
        alert("Hello, " + name);
    }

    proto.sayHello = sayHello;
}(Array.prototype));

var array = []; // or `new Array();`
array.sayHello("James");
```

Let's call it mixin prototype pattern :-)